# How can I get exact time labels in x-axis of a Matlab plot?

Tags: matlab, date, datetime

I am trying to get the exact time in x-axis. I am not sure why Matlab is taking intermediate times:

```
plot(t(:,2),t(:,1));
datetick('x','dd-mmm hh:MM','keepticks')
set(gca,'XTickLabelRotation',60);
```

[image: This is what I get]

But the x-axis should be a multiple of 5 minutes according to the data. For example:

```
datestr(t(1:5,2), 'yyyymmdd.hhMMss')

ans =

20040916.185000
20040916.185500
20040916.190000
20040916.190500
20040916.191000
```

Raw dataset where Col 1 is the yaxis and Col 2 is datenum

```
0   732206.784722222
0   732206.788194445
0   732206.791666667
0   732206.795138889
2.50000009934108e-05    732206.798611111
0.000116666667163372    732206.802083333
0.00110000002632538 732206.805555556
0   732206.809027778
0.000383333342770736    732206.812500000
0.000199999998013179    732206.815972222
0.000566666665176551    732206.819444445
0.00144166665772597 732206.822916667
0.00450000004221996 732206.826388889
0.00399166673670213 732206.829861111
0.00164166670292616 732206.833333333
0.00181666669249535 732206.836805556
0.00170000002284845 732206.840277778
0   732206.843750000
0.000525000018378099    732206.847222222
0.00137500000745058 732206.850694445
0.00121666670093934 732206.854166667
0.000500000019868215    732206.857638889
5.83333323399226e-05    732206.861111111
0   732206.864583333
0   732206.868055556
0   732206.871527778
0   732206.875000000
0   732206.878472222
0   732206.881944445
0   732206.885416667
0   732206.888888889
0   732206.892361111
0   732206.895833333
0   732206.899305556
0   732206.902777778
0   732206.906250000
0   732206.909722222
0   732206.913194445
0   732206.916666667
0   732206.920138889
0   732206.923611111
0.000416666674117247    732206.927083333
0.00212500003476938 732206.930555556
0.00308333337306976 732206.934027778
0.00501666667312384 732206.937500000
0.00619999998311202 732206.940972222
0.00663333335022132 732206.944444445
0.00845833330849806 732206.947916667
0.00887500002731880 732206.951388889
0.0112750000804663  732206.954861111
0.0158166667843858  732206.958333333
0.0192500000571211  732206.961805556
0.0203916667004426  732206.965277778
0.0113416666562359  732206.968750000
0.0270250000754992  732206.972222222
0.0274499999706944  732206.975694445
0.0287749999463558  732206.979166667
0.0110583333745599  732206.982638889
0.0114916666299105  732206.986111111
0.00115833335618178 732206.989583333
0   732206.993055556
0   732206.996527778
0   732207
0   732207.003472222
0   732207.006944445
0   732207.010416667
0   732207.013888889
0   732207.017361111
0   732207.020833333
0   732207.024305556
0   732207.027777778
0   732207.031250000
0   732207.034722222
0   732207.038194445
0   732207.041666667
0   732207.045138889
0   732207.048611111
0   732207.052083333
0   732207.055555556
0   732207.059027778
0   732207.062500000
0   732207.065972222
0   732207.069444445
0   732207.072916667
0   732207.076388889
0   732207.079861111
0   732207.083333333
0   732207.086805556
0   732207.090277778
0   732207.093750000
0   732207.097222222
0   732207.100694445
0   732207.104166667
0   732207.107638889
0   732207.111111111
0   732207.114583333
0   732207.118055556
0   732207.121527778
0   732207.125000000
0   732207.128472222
0   732207.131944445
0   732207.135416667
0   732207.138888889
0   732207.142361111
0   732207.145833333
0   732207.149305556
0   732207.152777778
0   732207.156250000
0   732207.159722222
0   732207.163194445
0   732207.166666667
0   732207.170138889
0   732207.173611111
0   732207.177083333
0   732207.180555556
0   732207.184027778
0   732207.187500000
0   732207.190972222
0   732207.194444445
0   732207.197916667
0   732207.201388889
0   732207.204861111
0   732207.208333333
0   732207.211805556
0   732207.215277778
0   732207.218750000
0   732207.222222222
0   732207.225694445
0   732207.229166667
0   732207.232638889
0   732207.236111111
0   732207.239583333
0   732207.243055556
0   732207.246527778
0   732207.250000000
0   732207.253472222
0   732207.256944445
0   732207.260416667
0   732207.263888889
0   732207.267361111
0   732207.270833333
0   732207.274305556
0   732207.277777778
0   732207.281250000
0   732207.284722222
0   732207.288194445
0   732207.291666667
0   732207.295138889
0   732207.298611111
0   732207.302083333
0   732207.305555556
0   732207.309027778
0   732207.312500000
0   732207.315972222
0   732207.319444445
0   732207.322916667
0   732207.326388889
0   732207.329861111
0   732207.333333333
```

Comment: For formatting reasons, Matlab decides on its own x axis scale for a figure. A simple example is plot(1:1000), where not the whole 1000 points are depicted. If you want to change the x tick distance programatically use Matlab's xticks function. You can do it also use the figure tool. This one you can find in Menu-> Tools->Edit Plot->X-Axis->Ticks->Step by

Comment: @MichaelC. You forgot to link something I think. Could you please show me how I can force it to use my numbers exactly

Comment: @MichaelC. How can I do this programmatically? Also, not sure how to use Step by since the plot starts from 16:48

Answer (score 1):

If you first specify exactly the ticks that you want to have like

```
set(gca, 'XTick', t(1:10:end,2))
```

and then adjust the display to date ticks (important to keep `'keepticks'`)

```
datetick('x','dd-mmm hh:MM','keepticks')
set(gca,'XTickLabelRotation',60);
```

will give you x-labels according to your original data.

For your example if you use

```
plot(t(:,2),t(:,1));
set(gca, 'XTick', t(3:12:end,2))
datetick('x','dd-mmm hh:MM','keepticks')
set(gca,'XTickLabelRotation',60);
```

exactly the full hours will be displayed.